Repost: Can someone help me out on this integral? (Leibniz’s Rule)
Evaluate $\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^n}$ by repeated differentiation of $\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{x^2+y^2}$
(This is from Kaplan’s Advanced Calculus, Self-Study)
I’ve tried the repeated differentiation and got $\frac π 2\left[\frac{(-1)^n n!}{x^{n+1}}\right]$ but is off from the answer
Edit: I’m making this edit for later responses. I would like to mention that this question is for my special projects course (highschool) where I independently explore higher mathematics on my own since there are no teachers that can help me to learn this kind of stuff. Thank you!

Going based off of Mathematica, the correct result is $\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^2}\frac{|x|^{1-2n}}{4^n}$.

Hint: Let $u=x^2$ and consider whether differentiating with respect to $u$ is simpler than doing so with respect to $x$.

For all $n \in \mathbb {N}$ and $a > 0$,
$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( {x}^{2} + {a}^{2} \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x
& = {\bigg[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{\left( {x}^{2} + t \right)}^{n}} \text {d} x \bigg]}_{t = {a}^{2}} \tag{1} \\
& = {\bigg[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{n - 1}}{\left( n - 1 \right)!} \cdot \frac {\text {d}^{n - 1}}{{\left( \text {d} t \right)}^{n - 1}} \frac {1}{{x}^{2} + t} \text {d} x \bigg]}_{t = {a}^{2}} \tag{2} \\
& = \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{n - 1}}{\left( n - 1 \right)!} \cdot {\bigg[ \frac {\text {d}^{n - 1}}{{\left( \text {d} t \right)}^{n - 1}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{{x}^{2} + t} \text {d} x \bigg]}_{t = {a}^{2}} \tag{3} \\
& = \frac {\pi}{2} \cdot \frac {{\left( - 1 \right)}^{n - 1}}{\left( n - 1 \right)!} \cdot {\bigg[ \frac {\text {d}^{n - 1}}{{\left( \text {d} t \right)}^{n - 1}} \frac {1}{{t}^{1 / 2}} \bigg]}_{t = {a}^{2}} \tag{4} \\
& = \frac {\pi}{{2}^{n}} \cdot \frac {\left( 2 n - 3 \right)!!}{\left( n - 1 \right)!} \cdot  {\bigg[ \frac {1}{{t}^{n - 1 / 2}} \bigg]}_{t = {a}^{2}} \tag{5} \\
& = \frac {\pi}{{\left( 2 a \right)}^{2 n - 1}} \binom {2 n - 2}{n - 1}. \tag{6}
\end{align}
$
From $(3)$ to $(4)$, we have let $x \mapsto {t}^{1 / 2} x$.
From $(5)$ to $(6)$, observe
$
\begin{align}
\left( 2 n - 3 \right)!!
& = \frac {\left( 2 n - 2 \right)!}{\left( 2 n - 2 \right)!!} \tag{A1} \\
& = \frac {1}{{2}^{n - 1}} \cdot \frac {\left( 2 n - 2 \right)!}{\left( n - 1 \right)!} \tag{A2} \\
& = \frac {\left( n - 1 \right)!}{{2}^{n - 1}} \binom {2 n - 2}{n - 1}. \tag{A3}
\end{align}
$
(Normally, I would have evaluated this integral using the beta function: Let $x \mapsto a {x}^{1 / 2}$.)

Define
$$I(x,n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^n}$$
for the boundary condition on $n=1$ this is a common integral and evaluates to:
$$I(x,1)=\frac{\pi}{2x}$$
and we easily get the point:
$$I(1,1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
taking the first derivative we get:
$$\partial_xI(x,1)=\int_0^\infty\frac{-2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy=-2x\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dy=-2xI(x,2)$$
and repeating:
$$\partial^2_xI(x,1)=\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{8x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^3}-\dfrac{2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\right)dy=8x^2I(x,3)-2I(x,2)$$
You can now try plugging these in , we have:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right)=-2xI(x,2)\Rightarrow -\dfrac{{\pi}}{2x^2}=-2xI(x,2)\Rightarrow I(x,2)=\frac{\pi}{4x^3}$$
Similarly,
$$I(x,3)=\frac{3\pi}{16x^5}$$
$$I(x,4)=\frac{5\pi}{32x^7}$$
we can see the denominator pattern easily as the constant goes up in powers of $2$ and so is $2^n$. Similarly, the power of $x$ increases by two each time and starts as $1$ and so must be $x^{2n-1}$.
The denominator is slightly harder to work out and may take a few more iterations to work out. It works out as:
$$\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(n-1)!}$$
but I do not have a nice way to get to this at the moment, I will try and make one.

A shortcut to a formula is to note that the numerators of your $I(x,n)$ terms are $1,1,3,5,\cdots$. If you compute a few more terms, the resulting sequence of numerators can be found on OEIS as A001790. That includes a number of different formulas.
